# Swift 3 making sha1, sha256 and md5 functions

Tags: swift3

In Swift 2, I used the following code to extend string variables and to be able to make sha1, sha256, and md5.

After moving to swift 3, the code is not working any more! I tried to convert it but run into continuous errors.

Any idea how can I solve this?

```
extension NSData {
    func hexString() -> String {
        var string = String()
        for i in UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(bytes), count: length) {
            string += Int(i).hexString()
        }
        return string
    }

    func MD5() -> NSData {
        let result = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))!
        CC_MD5(bytes, CC_LONG(length), UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(result.mutableBytes))
        return NSData(data: result)
    }

    func SHA1() -> NSData {
        let result = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))!
        CC_SHA1(bytes, CC_LONG(length), UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(result.mutableBytes))
        return NSData(data: result)
    }

    func SHA256() -> NSData {
        let result = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        CC_SHA256(bytes, CC_LONG(length), UnsafeMutablePointer(result!.mutableBytes))
        return NSData(data: result!)
    }
}

extension String {
    func hexString() -> String {
        return (self as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!.hexString()
    }

    func MD5() -> String {
        return (self as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!.MD5().hexString()
    }

    func SHA1() -> String {
        return (self as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!.SHA1().hexString()
    }

    func SHA256() -> String {
        return (self as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!.SHA256().hexString()
    }

}
```

Comment: "Not working anymore" = ?

Comment: means it needs changes to the swift 3 way :(

Comment: Have you tried the migrator (doesn't look like)?

Comment: I did, but didn't success. so I placed the original code here

Comment: See [MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512 (Swift 3)](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/7885/cryptographic-hashing/25614/md2-md4-md5-sha1-sha224-sha256-sha384-sha512-swift-3) in Documentation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'd better use Swift `Data` in Swift 3.

[Data](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data)

And when working with `Data`, you need to use `withUnsafeBytes(_:)` or `withUnsafeMutableBytes(_:)`, where you were using `bytes` or `mutableBytes` respectively.

[withUnsafeBytes(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1780450-withunsafebytes)

[withUnsafeMutableBytes(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779823-withunsafemutablebytes)

```
extension Data {
    func hexString() -> String {
        let string = self.map{Int($0).hexString()}.joined()
        return string
    }

    func MD5() -> Data {
        var result = Data(count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        _ = result.withUnsafeMutableBytes {resultPtr in
            self.withUnsafeBytes {(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
                CC_MD5(bytes, CC_LONG(count), resultPtr)
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    /*
    ... nearly the same for `SHA1` and `SHA256`.
     */
}

extension String {
    func hexString() -> String {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)!.hexString()
    }

    func MD5() -> String {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)!.MD5().hexString()
    }

    /*
    ... nearly the same for `SHA1` and `SHA256`.
     */
}
```

I prefer making computed properties than no-argument methods (for relatively light-tasks). You need to fix all parts using them, but you can write something like this:

```
extension Int {
    var hexString: String {
        return ...
    }
}
extension Data {
    var hexString: String {
        let string = self.map{Int($0).hexString}.joined()
        return string
    }

    var MD5: Data {
        var result = Data(count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        _ = result.withUnsafeMutableBytes {resultPtr in
            self.withUnsafeBytes {(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
                CC_MD5(bytes, CC_LONG(count), resultPtr)
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    /*
    ... nearly the same for `SHA1` and `SHA256`.
     */
}

extension String {
    var hexString: String {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)!.hexString
    }

    var MD5: String {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)!.MD5.hexString
    }

    /*
    ... nearly the same for `SHA1` and `SHA256`.
     */
}
```

---

There may be a quicker fix for your code using `NSData`, but I recommend you to move to `Data` in Swift 3.

Comment: Great solution. The `Int` extension is actually not needed. `hexString` in `Data` can be simply created with `self.map{ String($0, radix:16) }.joined()`

Comment: @vadian, thanks for your comment. But `String($0, radix:16)` in your code needs to be something like `String(format: "%02X", $0)`. `String($0, radix:16)` generates variable length String, 1...2 ("0"..."FF"). You cannot retrieve the original byte sequence without each byte taking fixed length representation. The length may be 2, very probably but not necessarily. So I have kept using the `Int` extension in the original code.

Comment: The body type of the `Data` map function is `UInt8` so the string length is always 2

Comment: @vadian, we have many this-must-be things in our minds, sometimes those can help us, sometimes prevent us from the right solution. So, I really appreciate any comments correcting my mistakes, but in this case, seems you are mistaking. Have you tested how this simple code works in an actual environment? `print(String((0x01 as UInt8), radix: 16))`

Comment: good, I updated the code and still facing problems of unresolved identifiers:

CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH,
CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH,
CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH,
 CC_LONG(),
 CC_MD5(),
 CC_SHA1(),
 CC_SHA256(),

Comment: @Hamid, I cannot find such behaviour, in my sample projects for macOS and iOS. Have you imported CommonCrypto in a usual manner? `#import "CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h"` in your {Project}-Bridging-Header.h

Comment: Oops, my bad :)

Comment: @OOPer, can you show us the implementation of the hexString var in the Int extension?

Comment: @Harris, many thing depend on what you really want to get, but I assumed something like this `extension Int{var hexString:String{return String(format: "%02X", self)}}` in the answer above.

Comment: See [MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512 (Swift 3)](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/7885/cryptographic-hashing/25614/md2-md4-md5-sha1-sha224-sha256-sha384-sha512-swift-3) in Documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
func MD5() -> String {

    let length = Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: length)
    if let d = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        d.withUnsafeBytes { (body: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
            CC_MD5(body, CC_LONG(d.count), &digest)
        }
    }
    return (0..<length).reduce("") {
        $0 + String(format: "%02x", digest[$1])
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find most of the answer ok, but if we should have a true universal solution I think we need to step it up a level.

`CC_LONG` is just an `UInt32` and will not support really large data structures.

This is my solution in **Swift 3**:

First we create a foundation that work with `Data`:

```
struct Sha256 {
    let context = UnsafeMutablePointer<CC_SHA256_CTX>.allocate(capacity:1)

    init() {
        CC_SHA256_Init(context)
    }

    func update(data: Data) {
        data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> Void in
            let end = bytes.advanced(by: data.count)
            for f in sequence(first: bytes, next: { $0.advanced(by: Int(CC_LONG.max)) }).prefix(while: { (current) -> Bool in current < end})  {
                _ = CC_SHA256_Update(context, f, CC_LONG(Swift.min(f.distance(to: end), Int(CC_LONG.max))))
            }
        }
    }

    func final() -> Data {
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count:Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        CC_SHA256_Final(&digest, context)

        return Data(bytes: digest)
    }
}
```

For convenience we do an extension for Data:

```
extension Data {
    func sha256() -> Data {
        let s = Sha256()
        s.update(data: self)
        return s.final()
    }
}
```

And last an extension for String:

```
extension String {
    func sha256() -> Data {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)!.sha256()
    }
}
```

If needed, convert the result from `Data` to hex string or something else depending on your use case.

This solution can be used for Sha512, MD5 etc. to get true universal solutions with Apple's CommonCrypto that are easy to extend to many different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

For completion, the shortest and most flexible solution in Swift 4 is:

```
extension Data {

    var hexString: String {
        return map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }

    var md5: Data {
        var digest = [Byte](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        self.withUnsafeBytes({
            _ = CC_MD5($0, CC_LONG(self.count), &digest)
        })
        return Data(bytes: digest)
    }

    var sha1: Data {
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        self.withUnsafeBytes({
            _ = CC_SHA1($0, CC_LONG(self.count), &digest)
        })
        return Data(bytes: digest)
    }

    var sha256: Data {
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        self.withUnsafeBytes({
            _ = CC_SHA256($0, CC_LONG(self.count), &digest)
        })
        return Data(bytes: digest)
    }

}

extension String {

    var md5: Data {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)!.md5
    }

    var sha1: Data {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)!.sha1
    }

    var sha256: Data {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)!.sha256
    }

}
```