# How to convert [UInt8] to ASCII in swift 3.0

Tags: swift, ascii

Use MD5 encrypted string,for16 byte [UInt8] array, but I also need to ASCII value,how to convert [UInt8] to ASCII in swift 3.0

Comment: In Swift 3 you can use `Data` as a replacement for `[UInt8]`. Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684092/swift-3-making-sha1-sha256-and-md5-functions

Comment: Please show at last a concrete example of input data and expected result. What is the ASCII value of an array? What should the ASCII value of `[0, 1, 100, 200]` be?

Comment: Most data bytes do not have an ASCII representation. If one needs to present data in ASCII the common approaches are to encode it to Base64 or hexadecimal.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
let asciiBytes: [UInt8] = [77,105,99,104,97,101,108]
let s = String(bytes: asciiBytes, encoding: .ascii)
print(s) // prints "Michael"
```

Answer (score 0):

Most data bytes do not have an ASCII representation, see the comment by Martin.

If one needs to present data in ASCII the common approaches are to encode it to Base64 or hexadecimal.